# Global Variables used across files in PHP

Tags: php

I have come across a situation where i need to use a queue and that should be accessible in all the pages . I tried it using Global variables but couldn't meet the requirement.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have a question?

Comment: I agree with alex... we may have answers.

Comment: Pretty sure the question is pretty well implied in the post.

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't constant data, you coud use a session var

```
some_page.php
<?php
   session_start(); //Never forget this line when using $_SESSION
   $_SESSION['queue'] = "my queue value";
?>

other_page.php
<?php
   session_start(); //Never forget this line when using $_SESSION
   $queue = $_SESSION['queue'];
   //use queue for your needs
?>
```

If it's constant data, you could put its value in a php file, and include it where you need.

```
queue.php
<?php
  $queue = "my queue value";
?>

some_file.php
<?php
  require_once "queue.php";
  echo $queue;
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you answering this non-question. The info was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create object (write class), where this queue will be stored, and pass this object (variable) into all methods/functions, where this queue is needed.

Comment: i need it for breadcrumbs to be used in every page

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (my)sql(ite) database to store your queue. It is super persistent and, once you get the hang of it, super easy to use.

Comment: So what is the difference between super persistent and just persistent? :P